# Another Spring + Hibernate + JPA question

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm, jpa

I'm still struggling with changing my Spring Application to use Hibernate with JPA to do database activities. Well apparently from a previous post I need an persistence.xml file. However do I need to make changes to my current DAO class?

```
public class JdbcProductDao extends Dao implements ProductDao {
    /** Logger for this class and subclasses */
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public List<Product> getProductList() {
        logger.info("Getting products!");
        List<Product> products = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query(
                "select id, description, price from products", 
                new ProductMapper());
        return products;
    }

    public void saveProduct(Product prod) {
        logger.info("Saving product: " + prod.getDescription());
        int count = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update(
            "update products set description = :description, price = :price where id = :id",
            new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("description", prod.getDescription())
                .addValue("price", prod.getPrice())
                .addValue("id", prod.getId()));
        logger.info("Rows affected: " + count);
    }

    private static class ProductMapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<Product> {

        public Product mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Product prod = new Product();
            prod.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            prod.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
            prod.setPrice(new Double(rs.getDouble("price")));
            return prod;
        }

    }

}
```

Also my Product.Java is below

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private Double price;

    public void setId(int i) {
        id = i;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append("Description: " + description + ";");
        buffer.append("Price: " + price);
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

I guess my question would be,
How would my current classes change after using Hibernate + JPA with an Entity Manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the section [12.6. JPA](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html#orm-jpa) of the [Chapter 12. Object Relational Mapping (ORM) data access](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html) in the official documentation? Everything you need to know is discussed there.

If this is an option, you should extend the `JpaDaoSupport` base class, it provides convenient methods like `get/setEntityManagerFactory` and `getJpaTemplate()` to be used by sublasses. If not, then get a `EntityManagerFactory` injected and use it to create a `JpaTemplate`. See the section [12.6.2. JpaTemplate and JpaDaoSupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html#orm-jpa-template) for more details on this.

Also have a look at [Getting Started With JPA in Spring 2.0](http://blog.springsource.com/2006/05/30/getting-started-with-jpa-in-spring-20/) for a more complete sample (the blog post is a bit old but is not really outdated) that will show you how to rewrite the methods of your DAO.

Comment: thank you, I'm not sure if it's just me but I have a hard time finding good documentation on Spring/Hibernate/JPA

Comment: Both JpaTemplate and JpaDaoSupport have been deprecated; also they have not been recommended by the spring team for a long time. Coding directly against the Java Persistence API should be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Moreover, I suggest you to read [this article: Generic DAO with Hibernate and Spring AOP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao.html), before deciding your design.

Comment: Thank you, that article gave me a little bit more of an idea on this